# Different tabBar icons in react navigation for selected and unselected state?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-navigation

I am setting up a tabbar using react navigation in react native. I am unable to setup multiple tabbar icons for selected/unselected state. Any reference or doc would help ?

Answer (score 8):

tabBarIcon callback provides you the **focused** variable for the same.

```
static navigationOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: 'Home',
    tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
        const image = focused 
        ? require('../active.png') 
        : require('../inactive.png')
        return (
            <Image 
                source={image}
                style={styles.tabIcon}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change the icon based on the [activeTintColor / inactiveTintColor](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab#tabBarOptions-for-TabBarBottom-default-tab-bar-on-iOS)

```
static navigationOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: 'Notifications',
    tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (tintColor == '#e91e63' ?
      <Image
        source={require('./activeIcon.png')}
        style={[styles.icon, {tintColor: tintColor}]}
      />
      :
      <Image
        source={require('./inactiveIcon.png')}
        style={[styles.icon, {tintColor: tintColor}]}
      />
    ),
    tabBarOptions: {
        activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
    }

};
```

You can do something like this even if you don't use the tint color.